# Fetch recent playlist from itunes

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, apple-music, apple-musickit

I need recent playlist which we played from apple music or iTunes from iPhone. So, If anyone has a demo, link or tutorial then please share with me. I am following "https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/AppleMusicWebServicesReference/GetRecentlyPlayed.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017625-CH62-SW1" but could not create "Music User Token" from store kit. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the demo related to the Music app and get some ideas about ["How to access the Music library and its properties with the MediaPlayer framework"](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-music-library-access--mobile-6188) from this link. Also, look into [the AVFoundation framework documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation).

Regarding the Music User Token, Just follow the Step from [creating Music private key to Music User Token](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/AppleMusicWebServicesReference/SetUpWebServices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017625-CH2-SW1). Also, don't forget the check the **"Notes"** in every section of this documentation. Maybe you will find some solution from that notes.

Comment: Already try but I found that "requestUserToken(forDeveloperToken:completionHandler:)" which method is given in doc this method only for ios11+. :)

Comment: @Mirant Right, it will work in iOS 11 and we can implement it in Xcode 9+. If you want to implement this feature then just install the iOS 11 beta version in any of the iPhone and then try it. Also, download the Xcode 9 beta version. :)